# Error return a NSString inside a block

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I'm trying to declare a method and return two values **BOOL, NSString** for that I'm doing:

```
typedef void(^myCompletion2)(BOOL, *NSString);
```

The problem with this code is that this command return the warning message:

> type specifier missing, defaults to 'int'

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the asterisk in the wrong place. Try:

```
typedef void(^myCompletion2)(BOOL, NSString*);
```

But really, this doesn't declare the block as returning anything. It returns nothing and takes two parameters, a `BOOL` and an `NSString`.